# could not create directory /home/hadoop/.ssh : permission denied?

Tags: linux, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I am configuring hadoop on Ubuntu os. I need to create RSA key pair to allow hadoop to interact with its nodes, so i running this command:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

then I get this:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa):
Could not create directory '/home/hadoop/.ssh': permission denied.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase ):
Enter same passphrase again:
open /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forgot to create `.ssh` dir in your home?

Try that:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
```

then re-run ssh-keygen.

Also possibly you doing ssh-keys creation from wrong user.. You started that shell using sudo?

Try to set HOME dir manually or enter right path in prompt.

Comment: even getting the same error, i think my hadoop user don't have root privilege. so how can i do that.

Comment: I'm confused that ssh-keygen want to save keys into dir that is not your home "/home/***hduser***/.ssh/id_rsa". Check your username and IDs: "echo $USER $HOME; id"

Comment: check your home dir for write permission "ls -ld ~". you must see something like that "drwxr-xr-x  XXX hadoop hadoop ... /home/hadoop". Permissions(at least for user) must be "rwx" (as shown).

Comment: when i run "ls -id ~" i am getting 1052235 /home/hadoop

Comment: Strange, it must output access rights. try "stat ~ -c%a". first number must be 7 (i.e. rwx)

Comment: "hadoop@ubuntu:~$ stat ~ -c%a" returns 755

Answer (score 1):

check your home directory name and permissions

```
             echo $HOME
             cd ~ ; ls -l 
             ls -l .ssh
             ls -lR .ssh
```

if above output is OK and you have correct permissions, perhaps your quota is full

try with "sudo" and see what happens...

Comment: cd ~ ; ls -l returns total 0

Comment: ls -l .ssh returns ls:cannot access .ssh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Seems like current user doesn't own the contents under home directory.

Gain the ownership as shown as below:

```
admin@mydb22-02:~$ sudo chown admin.admin /home/admin/
admin@mydb22-02:~$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4096 Nov  3 23:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin admin 4096 Dec 23  2012 ..
-rw------- 1 admin admin  191 Feb 13  2013 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  220 Apr  3  2012 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 3486 Apr  3  2012 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  675 Apr  3  2012 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin    0 Nov  3 23:29 .sudo_as_admin_successful
-rw------- 1 admin admin 4221 Nov  3 20:31 .viminfo
```

generating keys would work now as .ssh directory will now be created and owned by current user after generating the assymetric keys

Answer (score 0):

```
I have spent arround 1 hr on this and finally got the solution. It is due to permission problem. You have to use chown for your 'hadoop user'.

1. First make hadoop directory.
cd /home 
mkdir hadoop
then check 'ls -l'. it gives result like :
drwxr-xr-x  2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Aug 22 22:17 hadoop

2. sudo chown hadoop.hadoop /home/hadoop/
3. Then run remaining command for key generater.
```